# Calculation of arrival time and removal time of each frame?

Tags: video, h.264, video-processing, hevc, h.265

From a HEVC encoded bit stream how can I get the arrival time and removal time of each frame ?
I am trying to get o/p similar to this
 [image]

Any suggestion would be of great help 
PS: this is the o/p of Elecard's x264 buffer analyzer